# Malformed URL Exception in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm encountering the following error when passing the URL which is stored as a string in an array: `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: "http://cdn.posh24.se/images/:profile/022439100375d87ad153ed7038a3d2ba6"`

I have saved the url in a String array imageURLs[] that store the URL as a String. When I pasted the link directly, `downloadImage.execute("http://cdn.posh24.se/images/:profile/022439100375d87ad153ed7038a3d2ba6").get()`, works flawlessly. But when I pass in the array reference to the URL, for example: `execute(imageURLs[0]).get()`, it throws me the above mentioned error.

The code to download the Bitmap from the net:

```
public class DownloadCelebImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        Bitmap resultImage;

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                URL imageURL = new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) imageURL.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                resultImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return resultImage;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                  
                return resultImage;
            }
        }
    }
```

The method call:

```
DownloadCelebImage downloadImage = new DownloadCelebImage();
        Bitmap fetchedCelebMugshot = null;
        int randomCelebIndex = getRandomCelebrity();
        try {
            String url = profileArray[randomCelebIndex][0];
            fetchedCelebMugshot = downloadImage.execute(url).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Note that, `profileArray[randomCelebIndex][0]` contains the link ("http://cdn.posh24.se/images/:profile/022439100375d87ad153ed7038a3d2ba6") to download the image. It raises the exception on execute(url).get().

**EDIT**

Check the correct solution in the comment of the answer below. It has been explained over there.

Comment: I think you need to provide more of the code. How do we know there isn't e.g. a bug clobbering the array, or it never initialized properly, or something like that?

Comment: @RBH..updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

The URL that you are using:

```
  http://cdn.posh24.se/images/:profile/022439100375d87ad153ed7038a3d2ba6
```

contains a `:` in the path.  The `:` character is a reserved character, and should be %-escaped.  A corrected version of the URL is

```
  http://cdn.posh24.se/images/%3Aprofile/022439100375d87ad153ed7038a3d2ba6
```

I don't know if the unescaped `:` would cause the problem you are experiencing.  In fact, I can't reproduce the exception with Java(tm).  So I suspect that this isn't the real problem.

---

You say:

> When I pasted the link directly,
>
> ```
> downloadImage.execute("http://cdn.posh24.se/images/:profile/022439100375d87ad153ed7038a3d2ba6").get()
> ```
>
> it works flawlessly. But when I pass in the array reference to the URL, for example:
>
> ```
> execute(imageURLs[0]).get(),
> ```
>
> it throws me the above mentioned error.

If we take what you say at face value, then there is only one logical explanation: `imageURLs[0]` does not contain that string at the point that it is used.

I know you said it does ... but it can't.

So what could be going one here?

- You could simply be mistaken. (It happens)
- It could be that URLs look like they are the same, but are subtly different.  (Read about [homoglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph).)
- This could be a problem caused by inadequate synchronization.  I think this is the most likely explanation.

If one thread is populating the `imageURLs` array and another thread is reading is AND the two thread are not synchronizing properly, then it is possible that the reading thread does not see correct value.  There are a couple of scenarios:

- The reading thread could be reading the array cell too soon.
- The writing thread (or another thread) could be overwriting the array cell, and the reading thread could be picking up the wrong version
- This could be a memory anomaly; e.g. due to the write to the array cell not being flushed to memory.  Java will only insert a memory barrier (e.g. cache flush instructions) at a synchronization point.  (Technically when there is a *happens before* relationship ... which covers other cases as well.)

Note that running the application with a debugger is liable to change the behavior of the program and/or show different values in the array than the reader thread is seeing.  Any evidence provided by the debugger should be treated with suspicion.

---

I suspect that the only way we can get to the bottom of this is if you write a complete [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that other people can run and observe the behavior that you are seeing.

Comment: Well I figured out what the problem was. Thank for your response but the issue had  nothing to do with `imageURLs[0]`. I cross checked whether it contained the URL and it did. The issue was that I was storing URL in the following format "URL" where URL itself was a string. So the value that was being passed to `execute()` was ""the path to the website"" (notice the pair of starting and trailing ""). I simply spliced the string url to remove the starting and trailing " and it worked like a gem. Thanks for the input though.